# Failing one test case with my Find Char after Nth occurance of a string method

Tags: java, eclipse

My assignment is to create the method getCharAfterNthOccurance(String text, int n, String target) that does the following:

```
/**
* If n is not positive, throws an IllegalArgumentException.
* 
* Otherwise, returns the character that follows the nth occurrence of the
* target inside the text.
* 
* If the target does not occur n times within the text, or if the nth
* occurrence is not followed by a character, throws NoSuchElementException.
*/
```

Without using any .substring methods. This the code I have so far:

```
public static char getCharAfterNthOccurrence (String text, int n, String target)
{
    // Your implementation goes here.  You will find the two-parameter .indexOf
    // method on strings very helpful.  Do not use any of the .substring methods, 
    // or your program will be too slow.
    if (target.length()>=text.length())
    {
        throw new NoSuchElementException();
    }
    if (n<=0 || text.length()==0)
    {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    }
    if (n>text.length()+target.length())
    {
        throw new NoSuchElementException();
    }
    if (nthOccurrence(text,target,n)==-1)
    {
        throw new NoSuchElementException();
    }
    if (target.equals(""))
    {
        return text.charAt(n-1);
    }
    if (n == 1)
    {
        return text.charAt(text.indexOf(target)+target.length());
    }
    return text.charAt(nthOccurrence(text,target,n)-1); 
}
public static int nthOccurrence(String str, String c, int n)
{
    int pos = str.indexOf(c);
    while (n-- > 0 && pos != -1)
    {
        pos = str.indexOf(c, pos+1);
    }
    return pos;
}
```

These are a few of the test cases:

```
@Test
public void testGetCharAfterNthOccurrence ()
{
    assertEquals('a', getCharAfterNthOccurrence("aaaaab", 1, "a"));
    assertEquals('a', getCharAfterNthOccurrence("aaaaab", 2, "a"));
    assertEquals('a', getCharAfterNthOccurrence("aaaaab", 3, "a"));
    assertEquals('a', getCharAfterNthOccurrence("aaaaab", 4, "a"));
    //assertEquals('b', getCharAfterNthOccurrence("aaaaab", 5, "a"));
    assertEquals('d', getCharAfterNthOccurrence("abcdefabcabczabcc", 1, "abc"));
    // assertEquals('a', getCharAfterNthOccurrence("abcdefabcabczabcc", 2, "abc"));
    assertEquals('z', getCharAfterNthOccurrence("abcdefabcabczabcc", 3, "abc"));        
    // assertEquals('d', getCharAfterNthOccurrence("abcDABCd", 1, "ABC"));
}
```

The ones that are commented out (//) are the ones that currently are failing and i'm not sure how to continue. The first failed test case gets a NoSuchElementException, the second failed test case expects a <99> but receives a <97>, and the third failed test case gets a NoSuchElementException probably because it's looking for the uppercase letters and not finding them. Any suggestions?

Comment: Please explain what do you mean by falling ?

Comment: java.lang.AssertionError: expected:<97> but was:<99> for the second failed test case It gives values that are a few numbers higher than what are expected. I'm not sure what it means by 97 or 99. Oh and with the first and last test cases it's giving me a NoSuchElementException because at least in the last case it's searching for the capital letters and i'm not sure how to make it ignore case

Comment: this is rather weird. Walking a token string would solve this problem in linear time, using indexOf several times is still going to be incredibly slow in comparison...